# watching cctv footage without internet explorer

Tags: security, software-rec, camera

long story short, i wanna set up ip cameras around my home. all methods i've found seems to be accessing footage (on microSD in camera) via internet explorer (hikvision cams). i wanna have it on separate LAN preferably on unix & w/o internet explorer.

i want access to live feed & to playback recorded vids.

i really like kerberos.io but it seems like it isnt suitable when i record video on microSD thats in camera. i went over dozen of other software but it all seems like they're focusing on (server and) recording video, i need just to view it.

another way i wanted go was vlc media player. i figured how play there live feed and how play h.246 but it seems you need to download that h.246 file first. plus its on two separate/far from each other (live & recorded) for older person to view.

is there some software for viewing live feed & playback in one place, for unix & without internet? thanks for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the live feed should be easy with VLC or just about any other player that can handle RTSP or ONVIF.

Viewing internally-stored recorded videos will be a bit trickier.  Some cameras might present a playback option via ONVIF, but I don't believe Hikvision cameras do.

Most Hikvision cameras have the option to record to external devices instead of their internal SD cards.  They usually will support both NFS and Samba.  You could have the cameras record to an NFS share and then view the recorded files with VLC or other local media player on linux.

Note that recording video over the network, ie. instead of the internal SD card, can be a heavy network load.  If you have the option, ALWAYS use a wired camera if at all possible (ie. PoE).  If wifi is your only option, plan your access points accordingly in order to handle the load.  If using wifi, you may also find that you need to use lower resolution and lower bitrates in order to get video that flows smoothly.

A high resolution, high bitrate, and high frame rate cameras can easily use 20-30Mbps of bandwidth... that's a lot for a shared wifi AP to handle. Plus, keep in mind that if you are recording over the network and viewing the camera at the same time, you will almost double the traffic.  On top of that, if you're viewing the video on a wifi laptop or mobile device, you'll add even more load to your AP.

I have 20 hikvision cameras around my house... most wired PoE with a few wifi cameras.  They are great cameras and work very well.  Wifi will not be your friend if you have more than a couple wireless cameras.  I really can't stress strongly enough to avoid wireless cameras if you can.  I have 3 commercial-quality Unifi AP's to handle the load and the wireless cameras keep them very, very busy.